# How to add custom tab to Team Web Access

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs

I'm using TFS 2010 with Team Web Access and I want to create custom tab on TWA. It is possible because http://urbanturtle.com/videos/ have same functionality (they've added two custom tabs).

How I add custom tab to TWA? Do I need change/add something to the database?

Comment: I have seen multiple projects that have done that. Maybe you can lean something of these projects. One of them is this one: http://tfstimesheet.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1):

We don't have a good extensibility model for that in 2010.  The Urban Turtle folks use a filter to rewrite the HTML, I believe.  Early on I believe they and some others would overwrite TFS files, but that breaks servicing (i.e., a patch wouldn't overwrite them, leaving the product in an inconsistent state).